# how to put if condition so that if input is give and when we remove the input

Tags: javascript

how to put if condition so that if input is give and when we remove the input,
so that there should be show write anything.

i want to put if statement ,so that if the input is empty ,then there should show "you have to write some thing"

```
var number = document.getElementById("think");
var out = document.getElementById("output");

number.addEventListener("input", sol);

function sol(){

    var one = parseInt(number.value);

    var ans = ((one-12)/2)/5;

    out.innerHTML = "this is what u have thinked in ur brain "+ans;
}
```

Comment: I don't get the problem, what are you trying to do?

Comment: post your HTML code as well.. not getting what you are trying to say.

Comment: i want to put if statement ,so that if the input is empty ,then there should show "you have to write some thing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`isNan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check whether the result of `parseInt` is a number.

```js
var number = document.getElementById("think");
var out = document.getElementById("output");

number.addEventListener("keyup", sol);

function sol(){

    var one = parseInt(number.value);
    if(isNaN(one))
    {
      out.innerHTML = "Yur brain sux";
    }
    else
    {
      var ans = ((one-12)/2)/5;

      out.innerHTML = "this is what u have thinked in ur brain "+ans;
    }
}
```

```html
Whatcha thinkin bro: <input type="numeric" id="think"><br>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the `placeholder` attribute in the input element.

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="you have to write some thing" />
```